# error with ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, system

I just have deleted some file of the operating system and I have access just from the terminal. 
Everything else is disappeared. Last think I did it was a the installation of a python interpreter. Is it likely to have some source list deleted. I dont know whether I can restore my system.

I dont know how to access my internet connection from the termial. So I cannot update or upgrade anything.

Another thing is that whatever I write on my terminal it doesn't appear but it remains invisible. So I should be careful what I type in otherwise I will make thing worse. In same cases I cant even see any feedback from my terminal This is even more confusing.

Is there any way out how to restore it a day before unless there is any other way more efficient

Thank you in advance

Vangjush Komini

Comment: Huh, how do you know then if your terminal is alive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not been clear on what has gone. But you should remember that if you boot from a live cd, you will be able to mount the hard drive and save your data to another place such as a USB disk. Depending on what kind of data is saved ono the machine, it may prove simpler for you to back up your data using the livecd, reinstall, then copy your data back.

Your description sounds more like a crashed X server than the command line - [CTRL][ALT][F1] will take you to the first terminal / command line, and you can debug from there.

If you remember what it was you changed software wise, you may try typing

```
sudo apt-get remove [packageyouadded]
```

for a package you installed and think broke something, or

```
sudo apt-get install [packageyoudeleted]
```

to reinstall something that is missing.

EDIT: As Andrejs points out, you can also ask your system to have a go at fixing any dependencies that are broken:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

without any package name. This will check for missing / broken programs that are stopping an installed program from running.

Comment: Nice answer. Perhaps you should mention install `-f` option too.